# Why doesn't CWAC-Camera support video for devices lower then API 11?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Just wondering why CWAC-Camera doesn't support video recording for API 11 and below.

Is it too much of a pain to implement video recording or is it the fact of the little use of Gingerbread and below devices now? Thanks.

Comment: one of the reasons is the lack of `Camera.setPreviewTexture ` on API < 11 ... but it seems like with some minor changes it can be used (with SurfacePreviewStrategy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, some of the methods that I am relying upon in the implementation are only available for API Level 11 and above.

Comment: Do you plan to move from ABS to ABC ?

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. I appreciate the camera library, it's come in handy.

Comment: @Selvin: As is noted on the project README, the entire project needs to be rewritten, largely from scratch, courtesy of Google's deprecation of the `Camera` API. A revised project will probably support both regular fragments and the fragments backport. However, there should be no need for the library to use `appcompat-v7`, as it does not really use the action bar itself. The only reason `cwac-camera` depends upon ActionBarSherlock was that Jake had specialized fragment subclasses that were needed.